# View system transformation by Ian Ashdown

Tags: matrix, camera-matrix

I am reading this book about to code your own radiosity renderer by Ian Ashdown [Book link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220690300_Radiosity_-_a_programmer%27s_perspective)

There is a chapter about view-camera transformation, particularly the normalization process when he transform the frustum pyramid into a unit cube

[image]

My problem with this transformation is that the author don't explain how the matrix's values are derived

[image]

I never saw such a complex computation to normalize the front and back clipping planes for example

Also he never explain why there is `1/2` translation offset in the x and y axis

Can anybody bring some light to me with respect to these esoteric formulas, I will be greatly grateful

Comment: Presumably, the $\frac12$ is just to deal with the fact that the unit cube is not centered at the origin.